# How can I connect my entity field to the same entity?

Tags: php, symfony, entity

I added to my entity "Category" a field "parentcategory" to be able to connect a category to another category:

```
class Category
{ 

 /**
  * @ORM\Id()
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
  * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
  */
  private $id;


  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parentcategory", referencedColumnName="id")
  *
  */
  private $parentcategory;



 public function getId(): ?int
  {
    return $this->id;
  }

  public function getParentcategory(): ?Parentcategory {
    return $this->parentcategory;
  }

  public function setParentcategory(?Parentcategory $parentcategory): self {
    $this->parentcategory = $parentcategory;

    return $this;
  }
```

I get the error message:

> The return type of method "getParentcategory" in class
>   "App\Entity\Category" is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
  public function getParentcategory(): ?Parentcategory {
    return $this->parentcategory;
  }

  public function setParentcategory(?Parentcategory $parentcategory): self  {
    $this->parentcategory = $parentcategory;

    return $this;
  }
```

to

```
  public function getParentcategory(): ?Category {
    return $this->parentcategory;
  }

  public function setParentcategory(?Category $parentcategory): self  {
    $this->parentcategory = $parentcategory;

    return $this;
  }
```

Because in your case return type is invalid class

Answer (score 1):

It's actually your setter that is causing issueyou need to set the exact class

```
public function setParentcategory(?Category $category): self {
$this->parentcategory = $category;

return $this;
```